# Example of algebraic group of type $G_2$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

Can anyone point me to a concrete realization of a reductive algebraic group of type $G_2$ over a field of positive characteristic?  I have some questions about how the adjoint action permutes certain subalgebras of the Lie algebra so I would like to be able to calculate the Lie algebra and the adjoint action directly.  It would be most helpful if the realization was given by specifying a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n$, for not insanely huge $n$, such that the upper triangular matrices formed a Borel.

Comment: You can realize G2 as the stabilizer of a trilinear form on a 7-dimensional vector space. See this paper by Ashbacher: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(87)90173-6